# How to make PyCharm 3.0 to add space after comment block or line

Tags: python, pycharm

Normally in version 2.7 I could add comments in python by pressing ctrl+slash.
Result:

```
# class A(object):
#     def blah(self):
#         pass
```

After installation of PyCharm 3.0.

```
#class A(object):
#    def blah(self):
#        pass
```

I was searching in `Setings > Project Setting > Code Style > Python` and could not find anything.

Also I checked `Settings > Keymap` But seems to it is impossible to edit anything there.
I tried also change keymap from Eclipse to different options but didn't help.

Annotation about right use of # with space. [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments)

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Quote he documentation:

> Block comments generally apply to some (or all) code that follows them, and are indented to the same level as that code. Each line of a block comment starts with a # and a single space (***unless it is indented text inside the comment***).

What you are perhaps referring to are inline comments, and I would totally agree with you.

In your case, it is indented, so its best to keep them the way they are. However, if you want to add a space after each comment `#` without too much hassle, you can do the following:

I got the cursor to be selected in the video by holding down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key and dragging with out mouse. I would not usually add an animated gif, but I have done so for clarity.

[image]